# Яка правильна артикуляція голосних звуків української мови?

Tags: фонетика, resource-request

Чи існують якісь підручники/вправи тощо з правильної артикуляції голосних звуків?
Цікавить не чергування звуків, наголошені/ненаголошені звуки й інші правила відповідності літер звукам (орфоепії), а саме правильна вимова (артикуляція) наголошених голосних звуків.

Перейшов на українську з російської, з приголосними ніби впорався, а з голосними ніяк не можу знайти потрібної інформації. (Різницю дуже чутно, наприклад, у [цьому відео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIkL99VoBsw), достатньо подивитися перші 20 секунд)

Оновлення:
Цікавить саме артикуляція голосних, а не орфоепія.
(Дякую, @Iryna, за термін)

Comment: Вправа одна: говорити. Говорити скрізь і з усіма, а найкраще – з тими, хто самі добре говорять українською, копіювати й наслідувати їх манеру говорити. За жодними підручниками цього не вивчити, жодними вправами наодинці цього не досягти.

Comment: Я не погоджуюся. Подеколи навіть два слова відкривають очі на звуки. Наприклад, те, що "в" - губно-губний звук. Перед тим, як я це прочитав, я взагалі не чув, що він відрізняється! Та сама історія з "щ". Про "дж"/"дз" чудовий і простий опис: це дзвінкі відповідники "ч"/"ц": язик ставиться так само.
Вибачте за купу зайвої інформації, просто я, по-перше, розмовляю зараз українською мовою майже з усіма (рідкісні винятки, принаймні 95% часу точно українською) і доволі багато слухаю. Я чую різницю, але відтворити її не можу.

Comment: Приголосні звуки завжди легше навчитися вимовляти, ніж голосні, у приголосних більше відмінностей у розташуванні орґанів мовлення, ніж у голосних. Одразу можу вам сказати, українські голосні завжди вимовляються однаково, як під наголосом, так і без нього, так само як у російській. Єдина відмінність – це вимова [укр. И  /ɪ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_unrounded_vowel) порівняно з [рос. Ы /ɨ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_central_unrounded_vowel). Там справа є зразки вимови, послухайте та почуйте різницю. Це все, що вам треба знати про українські голосні звуки.

Comment: Є дуже багато правил щодо вимови ненаголошених звуків, вони часто наближуються один до одного (особливо и/е, яскравий приклад: "виделка"). Їх я вивчив. Наскільки мені відомо, ВСІ українські голосні відрізняються від схожих російських. Найяскравіше дійсно відрізняється "и" укр. від "ы" рос., проте й решта не вимовляються однаково. Дуже дякую за допомогу, вибачте, що сперечаюся. Просто з цим питанням мені, напевно, зможуть допомогти лише ті, хто вже пройшов шлях переходу з російської на українську, чи якісь актори/диктори, у яких мають бути якісь вправи (сподіваюся).

Comment: _актори/диктори, у яких мають бути якісь вправи_ це вправи на артикуляцію. За пошуком, є багато сайтів з такими вправими, але я, нажаль, не можу оцінити їх якість

Answer (score 9):

Вам знадобляться спочатку теорія, а потім практика.

Для **теорії** перегляньте [правила фонетики](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) і [орфоепію](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) української мови.

Для **практики** слухайте, як говорять. Як хороший приклад, можу порадити [Театр перед мікрофоном](http://www.nrcu.gov.ua/prog.html?id=354) Національного радіо, там диктори правильну вживають мову, не вживають русизмів і мають чітку вимову.